# Vertical alignment in a position-fixed div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment, fixed

I have a div, inside a bootstrap column, that has class position-fixed so that the contents inside are fixed relative to the viewport. I am able to horizontally align these contents but I am having trouble vertically aligning it.

I know there are many methods out there in bootstrap 4, but it all seems to break due to the position-fixed class. Either the contents disappear somewhere outside the page, or nothing happens.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">

            <div class="position-fixed h-100 col-md-auto">
                <div class="text-center vertical-center">
                    <h2>Title</h2>
                    <p>Subtext</p>
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal" href="#">Click me</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div
```

Comment: I'd ditch your fixed position and vertical-center and add `align-items-center` to your row and be done with it.

Comment: The fixed position is required. I need the content to be fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply Bootstrap's [flexbox utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#align-items) to the parent of the div you're trying to center ([this](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/) is a good cheatsheet of what different flex properties do if you need it):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    
                <div class="position-fixed h-100 col-md-auto d-flex align-items-center">
                    <div class="text-center vertical-center">
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <p>Subtext</p>
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal" href="#">Click me</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
    </div>
```

Specifically, adding d-flex and align-items-center should work.

Answer (score 4):

If you want it to be fixed position, there's no reason to contain it inside the other elements (`container`, `row`, `col`) since as you said, it's positioning is relative to the viewport. Therefore, use custom CSS to center it...

```
.vertical-center {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/rtOA3jgjPG

---

**Or**, to use the Bootstrap classes, make the fixed element a flexbox container using `d-flex`, and then `align-items-center` to center.

```
<div class="position-fixed h-100 col-md-auto d-flex align-items-center">
      <div>centered content</div>
<div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/TmySmKXXjC

Answer (score 0):

```
#OuterDiv {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#InnerDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position: relative;
}
```